# Code of Bivariate Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function in R

Tags: r

Hi: I am trying to obtain the code of this function in R but there is no way. There was a package called mecdf in R but now is not available. Could someone help me please ?

Comment: How about retrieving an [old version of this package](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mecdf/)?

Answer (score 0):

@VincentGuillemot put the answer as a comment -- deprecated packages like that are archived on CRAN.

The link is: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mecdf/

The code is:

```
mecdf = function (x, continuous=FALSE, ...,
    validate=TRUE, expand=continuous, project=FALSE, expandf=0.1)
  { x = cbind (x)
    nraw = nr = nrow (x)
    nc = ncol (x)
    if (validate)
    {   if (length (list (...) ) > 0)
            stop ("invalid constructor argument")
        if (!is.numeric (x) ) stop ("x must be numeric")
        if (!all (is.finite (x) ) ) stop ("all x must be finite")
        for (j in 1:nc) if (length (unique (x [,j]) ) < 2)
            stop ("each variable requires at least 2 distinct realisations")
        if (nc == 1) x [] = sort (x)
        if (is.null (colnames (x) ) ) colnames (x) = paste ("x", 1:ncol (x), sep="")
        if (is.null (rownames (x) ) ) rownames (x) = 1:nr
    }
    if (expand)
    {   nr = nr + 2
        a = b = numeric (nc)
        for (j in 1:nc)
        {   xrng = range (x [,j])
            xf = expandf * diff (xrng)
            a [j] = xrng [1] - xf
            b [j] = xrng [2] + xf
        }
        x = rbind (a, x, b)
    }
    if (project)
        for (j in 1:nc) x [,j] = (order (order (x [,j]) ) - 1) / (nr - 1)
    Fh = Fst = NULL
    if (nc > 1)
    {   if (continuous)
        {   Fh = .mecdf.continuous
            Fst = .mecdf.vertex
        }
        else Fh = FUNCTION (.mecdf.step)
    }
    else
    {   if (continuous) Fh = .uecdf.continuous
        else Fh =.uecdf.step
    }
    extend (FUNCTION (.mecdf.main), "mecdf", continuous, Fh, Fst, nraw, nr, nc, x)
  }

  .mecdf.main = function (u)
  { if (.$nc > 1)
    {   if (!is.matrix (u) ) u = rbind (u)
        if (.$nc != ncol (u) )
            stop ("k-variate mecdf requires k-column matrix")
        .mecdf.interpolate (.$Fh, .$Fst, .$nr, .$nc, .$x, u)
    }
    else
    {   if (is.matrix (u) && ncol (u) > 1)
            stop ("univariate mecdf doesn't accept multicolumn matrix")
        .uecdf.interpolate (.$Fh, .$nr, .$x, u)
    }
  }

  print.mecdf = function (m, ...)
  { variate = if (m$nc == 1) "univariate"
    else if (m$nc == 2) "bivariate"
    else paste (m$nc, "-variate", sep="")
    type = if (m$continuous) "continuous" else "step"
    cat ("mecdf_{", variate, ", ", type, "}\n", sep="")
    print (samp (m$x) )
  }

  plot.mecdf = function (m, ...)
  { p = m (m$x)
    if (m$nc == 1) .uecdf.plot (m, p, m$continuous, ...)
    else if (m$nc == 2) .becdf.plot (m, p, ...)
    else stop ("s3x_plot.mecdf only supports univariate and bivariate models")
  }

  .uecdf.plot = function (e, p, continuous, ...)
  { xlab = colnames (e$x)
    ylab = "Fh(x)"
    if (continuous)
        plot (e$x, p, ylim=c (0, 1), yaxs="i", type="l", xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab, ...)
    else
    {   plot (e$x, p, ylim=c (0, 1), yaxs="i", xlab=xlab, ylab=ylab, pch=NA, ...)
        x1 = e$x [-e$nr]
        x2 = e$x [-1]
        p0 = p [-e$nr]
        segments (x1, p0, x2, p0)
        segments (e$x, c (0, p), e$x, c (p, 1) )
    }
  }

  .becdf.plot = function (e, p, lines=TRUE, lty=1, col=rgb (0.975, 0.7, 0), ...)
  { labs = colnames (e$x)
    x1 = e$x [,1]; x2 = e$x [,2]
    plot (x1, x2, xlab=labs [1], ylab=labs [2], pch=NA, ...)
    if (lines)
    {   segments (x1, x2, x1 - 2 * diff (range (x1) ), x2, lty=lty, col=col)
        segments (x1, x2, x1, x2 - 2 * diff (range (x2) ), lty=lty, col=col)
    }
    text (x1, x2, round (p, 2) )
  }
```

Comment: @QuintinCopete Did you get this to work? In what version of R? I am having all sorts of trouble in 3.2.