# Efficient computation of bivariate empirical cdf in R/Fortran

Tags: r, empirical-distribution

Given an n*2 data matrix X I'd like to calculate the bivariate empirical cdf for each observation, i.e. for each i in 1:n, return the percentage of observations with 1st element not greater than X[i,1] and 2nd element not greater than X[i,2].

Because of the nested search involved it gets terribly slow for n ~ 100k, even after porting it to Fortran. Does anyone know if there's a better way of handling sample sizes like this?

**Edit**: I believe this problem is similar (in terms of complexity) to finding Kendall's tau, which is of order O(n^2). In that case Knight (1966) has an algorithm to reduce it to O(n log(n)). Just wondering if there's any O(n*log(n)) algorithm for finding bivariate ecdf already out there.

**Edit 2**: This is the code I have in Fortran, as requested. This is called in R in the usual way, so the R code is omitted here. The code is meant for arbitrary dimensions, but for the specific thing I'm doing a bivariate one is good enough.

```
! Calculates multivariate empirical cdf for each point
! n: number of observations
! d: dimension (>=2)
! umat: data matrix
! outvec: vector of ecdf

subroutine mecdf(n,d,umat,outvec)
    implicit none

    integer :: n, d, i, j, k, tempsum
    double precision, dimension(n) :: outvec
    double precision, dimension(n,d) :: umat
    logical :: flag

    do i = 1,n
        tempsum = 0
        do j = 1,n
            flag = .true.
            do k = 1,d
                if (umat(i,k) < umat(j,k)) then
                    flag = .false.
                    exit
                end if
            end do
            if (flag) then
                tempsum = tempsum + 1
            end if
        end do
        outvec(i) = real(tempsum)/n
    end do
    return
end subroutine
```

Comment: A simple data example might have prompted earlier efforts at proposing a solution. Does seem like a necessarily O(n*m) problem, but I do not see any search involved.

Comment: The `mecdf` package used to do this, although is now not on CRAN anymore. Anyway, you can find the old versions here: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mecdf/

Comment: @nicola I've tried that package suggested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682550/code-of-bivariate-empirical-cumulative-distribution-function-in-r) but couldn't get it to work. I'm not sure whether it does everything inside R, in which case it's even slower.

Comment: I can think of one possibility but my rule on SO is that I don't start coding until a MWE is presented.

Comment: I've added the Fortran code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think my first effort was not really an ecdf, although it did map the points to the interval [0,1] The example, a 25 x 2 matrix generated with:

```
#M <- matrix(runif(100), ncol=2)
M <- 
structure(c(0.0468267474789172, 0.296053855214268, 0.205678076483309, 
0.467400068417192, 0.968577065737918, 0.435642971657217, 0.929023026255891, 
0.038406387437135, 0.304360694251955, 0.964778139721602, 0.534192910650745, 
0.741682186257094, 0.0848641532938927, 0.405901980120689, 0.957696850644425, 
0.384813814423978, 0.639882878866047, 0.231505588628352, 0.271994129288942, 
0.786155494628474, 0.349499785574153, 0.279077709652483, 0.206662984099239, 
0.777465222170576, 0.705439242534339, 0.643429880728945, 0.887209519045427, 
0.0794123203959316, 0.849177583120763, 0.704594585578889, 0.736909110797569, 
0.503158083418384, 0.49449566937983, 0.408533290959895, 0.236613316927105, 
0.297427259152755, 0.0677345870062709, 0.623845702270046, 0.139933609170839, 
0.740499466424808, 0.628097783308476, 0.678438259987161, 0.186680511338636, 
0.339367639739066, 0.373212536331266, 0.976724133593962, 0.94558056560345, 
0.610417427960783, 0.887977657606825, 0.663434249348938, 0.447939050383866, 
0.755168803501874, 0.478974275058135, 0.737040047068149, 0.429466919740662, 
0.0021107573993504, 0.697435079608113, 0.444197302218527, 0.108997165458277, 
0.856855363817886, 0.891898229718208, 0.93553287582472, 0.991948011796921, 
0.630414301762357, 0.0604106825776398, 0.908968194155023, 0.0398679254576564, 
0.251426834380254, 0.235532913124189, 0.392070295521989, 0.530511683085933, 
0.319339724024758, 0.534880011575297, 0.92030712752603, 0.138276003766805, 
0.213625695323572, 0.407931711757556, 0.605797187192366, 0.424798395251855, 
0.471233424032107, 0.0105366336647421, 0.625802840106189, 0.524665891425684, 
0.0375960320234299, 0.54812005511485, 0.0105806747451425, 0.438266788609326, 
0.791981092421338, 0.363821814302355, 0.157931488472968, 0.47945317090489, 
0.906797411618754, 0.762243523262441, 0.258681379957125, 0.308056800393388, 
0.91944490163587, 0.412255838746205, 0.347220918396488, 0.68236422073096, 
0.559149842709303), .Dim = c(50L, 2L))
```

So the task is to do a single summation of a two-part logical test on N items which I suspect is O(N*3). It might be marginally faster if implemented in Rcpp, but these are vectorized operations.

```
# Wrong: ecdf2d <- function(m,i,j) { ord <- rank(m[ , 1]^2+m[ , 2]^2)
#            ord[i]/nrow(m)}  # scales to [0,1] interval

ecdf2d.v2 <- function(obj, x, y) sum( obj[,1] < x & obj[,2] < y)/nrow(obj)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this in R --- it is very slow when the data matrix gets large and that's why I turned to Fortran. I think it's still O(N^2) since you will have to loop over x,y (so that x=M[i,1], y=M[i,2], i from 1 to n so O(n) here). Although the inner comparison is vectorized, the outer isn't (but please correct me if it's wrong).

Comment: I don't see an implicit double loop over  the number of rows times number of rows. Instead there are two implicit single loops over the number of rows rather than a loop within a loop.

Comment: I understand your point, but this is slower than the double loop coded in Fortran (I have this exact same code in R and it took more than 2 minutes for n=30k). I wonder if a similar thing could be coded in Fortran. More importantly is that the complexity doesn't grow as fast as O(n^2) - I don't know yet what's the sample size I need eventually, but it's likely to be at least 100k, and thus it needs to be rather efficient.

Thanks again!